# Why does bash return true when searching an array for part of an element?

Tags: bash

I am working on a bash script, and I can't figure out why I'm seeing a certain behavior.

I declare an array of month names, like this:

```
declare -a months=("january" "february" "march" "april" "may" "june" "july" "august" "september" "october" "november" "december")
```

And then I have a loop that prompts the user for input for a month.  If the month they enter is invalid, then it continues to prompt them for another month.  The loop reads like this:

```
month=
while [[ -z ${month} ]]
do
echo -e "\nPlease enter a month, for example, \"November\"."
read month
if [[ ! "${months[*]}" =~ "${month,,}" ]] ; then
    echo -e "\nInvalid month; please check your spelling and try again."
    month=
fi
done
```

This works if I enter a string that is nothing like an entry in "months".  So for example, if I enter "septiembre," the program works as expected.

However, if I enter a portion of a month string, for example, "nov" or "mber," the program takes that as valid and continues.

Why is bash returning true when a user-entered input matches a portion of a string in the array?  Why isn't it looking to see if the strings are a 100% match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the regular expression operator, so (as a simple example) "january february" will match the regex `jan` (or even the regex `ry fe`). In order to check if an input is an element of the array, use an associative array.

```
declare -A months=([january]=1 [february]=2 ...)
```

If you are using `bash` 4.2 or later, it's as simple as

```
if [[ ! -v months[${month,,}] ]]; then
```

For `bash` 4.0 or 4.1, you can use

```
if [[ -z ${months[${month,,}]} ]]; then
```

Comment: This did it; I'm using bash 4.1 and your suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's because `"${months[*]}"` expands to a single string of the array members joined with spaces and you're matching against that string.

You could solve this by adding spaces:

```
[[ ! " ${months[*]} " =~ " ${month,,} " ]]
```

**Edit**:

The above works for me (for all your examples) on **4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)** and **4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)**. The whole code is below (only the spaces have been added).

```
declare -a months=("january" "february" "march" "april" "may" "june" "july" "august" "september" "october" "november" "december")
month=
while [[ -z ${month} ]]
do
echo -e "\nPlease enter a month, for example, \"November\"."
read month
if [[ ! " ${months[*]} " =~ " ${month,,} " ]] ; then
    echo -e "\nInvalid month; please check your spelling and try again."
    month=
fi
done
```

**Edit2**:
    To filter out inputs with spaces and thereby prevent false positives on "february martch", etc.:

```
if [[ "${month}" =~ " " || ! " ${months[*]} " =~ " ${month,,} " ]]; then
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but adding the spaces doesn't appear to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you add them both at the left hand side and at the right hand side?

Comment: Yes, I added them on both sides.

Comment: Edit to my last comment, in response to your edits: I was wrong in my first reply, this is another solution to the problem.  I was, as you said, initially missing one space mark.  Marking this as the answer, since you replied first; chepner's response also worked.

Comment: @thatotherguy, I just tried your example, and it does indeed accept that as input.

Comment: @JayneCobb's_HatDesigner Yup. Didn't realize that inputs could have spaces. You could do `if [[ "${month}" =~ " " || ! " ${months[*]} " =~ " ${month,,} " ]]` ; then` to filter out inputs with spaces first.